# Ruby on Rails - Return all records where child record matches element in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

This sounds kind of complicated from the title, but it really shouldn't be. I'm using Rails for an API, and have an endpoint which accepts an array of items. I want to return all records where the records that belong to it match at least one of the elements in the array.

For example, say I'm making a blog, and I have Posts and Tags.

I might request something like:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts_by_tag?tags=news,weather,life
```

then in **routes.rb**

```
get '/posts_by_tag' => 'posts#index_by_tag'
```

and in **posts_controller.rb**

```
def index_by_tag
  tags =  params[:tags].split(',')
  @posts = Post.where( any element in Post.tags matches any element in tags )
  render json: @posts.to_json, status: :ok
end
```

In the hypothetical example above, I would want to return all posts which had a tags for any of "News", "Weather", or "Life".

I'm coming from node, and haven't been spending much time with Rails recently. But this feels like a situation where there is a very well-defined Rails/ActiveRecord way of doing this.

Comment: What kind of an array is it? What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using Postgres, and the array is just whatever type of array is generated by Ruby's String.split() method.

Comment: But what type of array is post.tags? Is it a Postgres-array?

Comment: It's an associated model. Post has_many tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have a model `Tag`, which is joined to `Post` by a model named, say, `PostTagging`.

```
class PostTagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :post_taggings
end
```

Hence, to get all posts with that tag all you need to do is to join `Tag` to `Post` and search for that `Tag` model:

`Post.joins(:tags).where(tags: { name: tags })`

You are allowed to do that `joins(:tags)` because you specified a relation inside `Post` and `tags` inside `where` is an array of tag names. Easy-peasy!

Comment: According to OP, there is no intermediate model, it's a direct `has_many`-association. Also, your example will return the same post multiple times if it has multiple matching tags in in the tags-array. `.distinct` should take care of this.

Comment: I cannot find where OP state he has no intermediate model, but if he don't then pankaj answer would work just fine :)

Comment: No, pankaj's answer only works checks for a single `tag`-attribute of the post.

Comment: Hi sorry, I should have been more clear about that. There is an associated model, as @shlajin correctly assumed. Its a many-to-many association through the post_taggings model. And this answer works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.where(tags: tags) => 
  SELECT `posts`.* 
  FROM `posts` 
  WHERE `posts`.`tags` 
  IN ('News', 'Weather', 'Life')
```